# What is SQL Server search algorithm when primary key is composite

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, algorithm, binary-search-tree

We know that best search algorithm is [Binary search tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree). Consider a primary key in a table that is composite. Does SQL Server use `BST` for search in data? If yes how it can search multiple columns with `BST`? If it does not use `BST` what other algorithm dose it use? And what is [Time complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity) of that algorithm?

Please share anything you know :)

Comment: SQL Server uses B-Tree to store indexes,but "B" mean balanced instead of binary.

Comment: Thanks I read about B-tree.but all examples are based on one value.If we have complex data how we can generate B-tree?

Comment: Use and Identity for the primary key. If your composite key needs to be unique, then you can create a unique key / index on it.

Answer (score 2):

It uses the exact same algorithm with the exact same complexity.

Imagine you have a single field PK with values 'A', 'B', 'C' and so forth - no problem, right?

Now imagine that those keys are instead 'AA', 'BB', 'CC' and so forth - no problem, right? This is just a two-char key.

A composite PK is just like 'AA' compared to 'A' - conceptually speaking. If your PK spans two 1-char columns with the value 'A' and 'B', your key could be compared to the single-column value 'AB'.

Simply, your key comparison now compares X fields instead of just one.

Answer (score 0):

Tree search depends on an abstract notion of a key. The key needs to be comparable to other keys, that is all. The search algorithm does not need to know if the key is composed of multiple fields. All it knows is that the key is comparable.

Comment: ok it knows that the key is comparable,it can use `linear search` or `B-Tree`.I want to know when key is composite how it can search values?

Comment: @Kerezo not sure I understand. A composite key is comparable (agreed?).